# CSS Buttons Alignment Problem in IE

Tags: css

Hi I have a problem with these buttons, they are a UL List basically, they render fine in Chrome, and Firefox, but on IE the right buttons go about -5 pixels more Top than where they should be.

```
<ul id="buttonList">
                <li id="analysis">
                    <img src="images/anaylsis.png" width="210" height="34" alt="analysis" />
                </li>
                <li id="calories">
                    <img src="images/calories.png" width="211" height="34" alt="calories" />
                </li>
                <li id="ingredients">
                    <img src="images/ingredients.png" width="210" height="35" alt="ingredients" />
                </li>
                <li id="feeding">
                <img src="images/feeding.png" width="211" height="36" alt="feeding" />
                </li>
            </ul>
```

This is the CSS. The commented lines are what I tried before, they still don't work.

```
#buttonList
{
padding: 0px;
}

#analysis
{
position: relative;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

#calories
{
position: relative;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

#ingredients
{
/*position: relative;
left: 220px;
top: -77px;
*/
margin-left: 220px;
margin-top: -77px;
} 

#feeding
{
/*
position: relative;
left: 220px;
top: -77px;
*/
margin-left: 220px;
margin-top: -0px;
}
```

I have this code set on top

```
* 
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

body
{
margin: 0px;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Well, for starters, if you really think about it, what is a negative margin? If you imagine the box model, how would that look? Try using relative positioning.

Comment: @corroded no I do not have a reset.css , what do you mean by that something to remove all the margins? I have this if it helps, i will put it in the post above

Comment: Maybe try adding `!important` to them?

Comment: @Anonymous I tried that out, didn't work.

Comment: yeah something like this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ there might also be some issue with the line-height etc so its best to try that reset first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Testded in IE6 / IE7, Chrome, FF*

> - **DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/obupe4

```
  #buttonList
{
    width: 430px; 
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding: 5px
}
  #buttonList li {
    margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
    display:inline;
    width: 211px;
    height: 36px
  }
```

Comment: This works in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE they are aligned undearneath each other.

Comment: that doesn't work at all then, they get aligned underneath each other that way

Comment: @Ryan Sammut: i have tested it personally in IE6/7 and it work fine. ;)

Comment: I must have done something wrong myself mate, any way it's working now, thanks a lot for your time, I appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Why do the images have different `height`/`width` attributes?

Surely you want images that are all the same dimensions to align them properly?

I changed all the `img` `height` attributes to `36` (and the `width`s to `210`), and used `float: left` and `margin-right` to align the images:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rm9hT/6/

Comment: This didn't work for me, they're being aligned underneath each other, all four of them

Comment: No, I don't want them underneath each other, I want them place 2 and 2 along side each other.

Comment: If you saw that fail comment, ignore it. I completely misunderstood you.

Comment: It's ok mate :) I understand you misunderstood hehe.

Comment: How about this, with an explicit width/height on the `ul`? http://jsfiddle.net/Rm9hT/8/ I'm not sure where you're putting this code, so I'm not sure why it's not working for you.